# Open New ViewController when textField is selected in tableView Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using one textField in my tableView and getting different data by using `indexPath.row` but the problem is I am trying to open a new `ViewController` when particular textfield is selected in `tableView`.

UITableViewCell class:

```
class AddCustomerCell: UITableViewCell {


@IBOutlet weak var textfield: SkyFloatingLabelTextField!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

}
```

UITableView datasource and delegate method:-

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 3
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customerCell", for: indexPath) as? AddCustomerCell else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    cell.textfield.delegate = self
    cell.textfield.placeholder = fieldArr[indexPath.row]["title"]
    cell.textfield.title = fieldArr[indexPath.row]["title"]
    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    if indexPath.row == 0 {

        cell.textfield.text = self.fullName
        cell.textfield.keyboardType = .default
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 1 {

        cell.textfield.text = self.email
        cell.textfield.keyboardType = .emailAddress
    }

    else if indexPath.row == 2 {
        cell.textfield.text = self.phoneNumber
        cell.textfield.keyboardType = .numberPad
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 3 {
        cell.textfield.text = self.areaSalesMen
        cell.textfield.keyboardType = .default
    }

    else {
        cell.textfield.isSecureTextEntry = false

    }

    return cell
}
```

UITableView didSelect row method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    print("index \(indexPath.row)")

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        print("full name is selceted")
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 1 {

    }
    else if indexPath.row == 2 {

    }
    else if indexPath.row == 3 {
        let vc = AreaSalesMenListViewController.instantiate(fromAppStoryboard: .Main)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

Here is UItextField extension:-

```
extension AddCustomerViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(forItem: textField) {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            //firstName
            self.fullName = textField.text ?? ""

        }
        else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            //lastName
            self.email = textField.text ?? ""

        }
        else if indexPath.row == 2 {
            //userId
            self.phoneNumber = textField.text ?? ""

        }
        else if indexPath.row == 3 {
            //asm
            self.areaSalesMen = textField.text ?? ""
            let vc = AreaSalesMenListViewController.instantiate(fromAppStoryboard: .Main)
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
```

I want to open new `ViewController` when the `textField` is selected in `indexPath.row == 3`. How can I do this. Please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `cellForRow` method add following line to set tag of textField:

```
cell.textfield.tag = indexPath.row
```

In `textFieldDidBeginEditing` add following code to detect selected textField in 4th row means `indexPath.row == 3`.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    if textField.tag == 3 {

        textField.resignFirstResponder()

        self.areaSalesMen = textField.text ?? ""
        let vc = AreaSalesMenListViewController.instantiate(fromAppStoryboard: .Main)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: @wings, Happy to help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

In `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` add your code to navigate and after that return false.

`textFieldShouldBeginEditing` is the first method which is called , this determines whether the textField should begin editing or not, since you don't want user to enter any text you can return false from this delegate method and perform you navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pushing your `viewController` in `textFieldDidEndEditing` write that in `textfieldShouldBeginEditing`, as when you tap on a `textField` the first delegate to get called is `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`.

```
extension AddCustomerViewController : UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(forItem: textField) {
            if indexPath.row == 3 {
                //asm
                self.areaSalesMen = textField.text ?? ""
                let vc = AreaSalesMenListViewController.instantiate(fromAppStoryboard: .Main)
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is working but the problem is when I am clicking done button it open new controller but not on when TextField begin editing

Comment: Yes. Thats happening because you have pushed your controller in `DidEndEditing`, it gets called when editing has ended, e.g pressing the done button, push inside `shouldBeginEditing` then whenever you will tap on textField, you will be pushed to your next controller.

Comment: I am facing one more problem is that when moving to new viewcontroller keyboard is not dismissed so its moving to again viewcontroller when back button is pressed

Answer (score 0):

In cellForRow :

```
if indexPath.row == 3 {
    textfield.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
}
```

and in didSelect :

```
if indexPath.row == 3 {
   // Push your controller
}
```